# Shell binary search with sorted input

Tags: shell, binary-search, ksh

I have coded **binary search** in **shell**, just for practice.

#### Input

Input data is already sorted set of numbers streamed to the script. `$1` is the sought number.

```
for i in {1..1000000}; do
    echo $RANDOM
done | sort -n | ./binsearch.ksh 10
```

#### Code

I use `ksh` as the fastest shell against `bash`, `zsh` and other bash clones, and as an interpreter that maintains lists - against `dash`.

Variables: `puppy` is the sought number; `swamp` is a sorted set of numbers.

```
#!/bin/ksh

puppy=$1; [ -z "$puppy" ] && {
    echo "@@@ No args specified."
    exit
}
size=0

while IFS= read -r line; do
    ((++size))
    swamp[${#swamp[*]}]=$line
done

echo

left=0
right=$(($size - 1))
while   [ $left -le $right ] ; do
    mid=$((($left + $right) >> 1))
#   echo "$left $mid(${swamp[$mid]})    $right"
    if      [ $puppy -eq ${swamp[$mid]} ]; then
        echo "$puppy    $mid"
        exit
    elif    [ $puppy -lt ${swamp[$mid]} ]; then
        right=$(($mid - 1))
    else
        left=$((mid + 1))
    fi
done
echo '</not found>'
```

Could you please tell what you think of this code and how can I improve it?

#### Note

I would care about **POSIX** compatibility if it was a chance to have lists in `dash`, but as far as there's none, I would have to use namespaces with `eval` and get my memory filled with 1e6 `swamp_43254`-like variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty cool to be able to do this in Bash.

#### Input validation

There are several issues here:

> ```
> puppy=$1; [ -z "$puppy" ] && {
>     echo "@@@ No args specified."
>     exit
> }
> ```

Code is most readable when there is one statement per line,
so I suggest to separate the variable assignment and the input validation steps.

`exit` without arguments exits with the code of the last command,
in this case 0 because the `echo` most probably succeeds,
so the program exits with success.
But it shouldn't. A common practice is to use exit code 2 for invalid usage.

Lastly, instead of not-valid-and-exit I think valid-or-else-exit is a somewhat cleaner logic, and also simpler to write:

```
puppy=$1
[ "$puppy" ] || {
    echo "@@@ No args specified."
    exit 2
}
```

#### Unnecessary `$size`

The `size` variable is unnecessary.
You can use `${#swamp[*]}` instead, for example in:

```
right=$((${#swamp[*]} - 1))
```

#### Unnecessary `$` inside `$((...))`

You can simplify these:

> ```
> mid=$((($left + $right) >> 1))
> right=$(($mid - 1))
> ```

Like this:

```
mid=$(((left + right) >> 1))
right=$((mid - 1))
```

Comment: Thank you! This increased performance and elegance of my code!